# I'm able to connect to my Postgres db with PGAdmin but not with npgsql (C#)

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, pgadmin

I'm able to connect to my remote server (Postgres), and my user is able to query tables.
When I'm trying to implement connection to this db I'm getting this error:

Unhandled exception. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XX.XX.XX", user "XXX", database "XXX", no encryption

```
 using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
```

Error is thrown in the open, I've tried many kind of connection string:

```
"Server=XXX;Port=5432;Timeout=1024;CommandTimeout=1024;UserId=XX;Database=XX;Password=XX;Database=XX"

"Host=XXX;Port=5432;Username=XX;Password=XX;Database=XX"
```

Same result at all the attempts.

I've asked to server owner to check pg_hba.conf, waiting for his response...
but I don't understand why PGAdmin is able to connect and not my C# NPG connection :/

Thanks

I need to connect to this remote postgres db.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
Updating the Npgsql library via Nuget did the trick for me.

I was on version 5.x.y, updated to 7.x.y.

Under the hood, I believe the issue may be a change in Npgsql's handling of the Connection String for the "SSL Mode" option.

See "SSL/TLS Improvements":
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html